# what happens between viewWilldisappear and viewDiddisappear?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

This is a follow up on a previous unsolved post.
I have a navcontroller, a tableview controller and a searchbar in the tableview. All this is built in storyboard.
I then build another viewcontroller programmatically when a cell is selected.
I do not want the navigation bar to appear in this last view so, in viewWillDisappear I call

```
 [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

This works just fine IF I select a cell in the main tableView.
However, if the cell is selected after narrowing the data from a search in searchbar, then, the navigationbar will appear in the subsequent view although the call to setNavigationBarHidden is made  in viewWillDisappear.

I tried repeating this call in viewDidDisappear and, now, the navigation bar disappears from the subsequent view although it is briefly displayed.

I would like to know what happens between the calls to viewWilldisappear and viewDiddisappear that apparently resets the NavigationBarHidden property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found: The NavigationBarHidden property is apparently reset because when the searchbar leaves the view, it will send the navigationbar again on the view.
I am not sure I understand exactly what is happening, but this line of code in my viewWillDisappear solves the problem:

```
 self.searchDisplayController.active=NO;
```

followed by:

```
   [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

Of course, I would love to hear from someone who really understands what happens here.